# How to fetch data from associative array in blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multidimensional-array, laravel-blade

I am trying to fetch keys of array separately and values separately.
actual output:

```
[  
   "IT" => [  
      "Programming" => [  
         0 => "Python" 1 => "Java"
      ],
      "Networking" =>  [  
         0 => "CCNA"
      ]
   ],
   "Business" => [  
      "Power BI" => [  
         0 => "Power BI foundation"
      ]
   ]
]
```

**desired output:**

```
[  
   "IT",
   "Business"
]
[  
   "Programming",
   "Networking"
]
```

Comment: What code did you use to fetch/generate those data? Also please explain the logic to group those keys together.

Comment: i am trying to fetch data from database using foreach loop to separate category, subcategory and product

Comment: Like catcon said, what is the logic to group those keys together?

Comment: i have an array which includes categories-sub categories and then items . Now i want to show this data on my blade in related manner . So what can be the code to do so?

Comment: basically to be more specific the array shows the relation between category, sub-category and product.
To get keys my logic, to separate categories, subcategories and product.

Comment: How is your output constructed? It looks like you are joining the sub-categories to the categories but what you desire is just getting all categories in one array and all sub-categories in another array, right? If so, "Power BI" should be included in the second array.

Comment: try array_keys()  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta, i tried using array_keys() but the subcategories are joined as one like ["Programming","Networking","Power BI"]
my desired output: ["Programming","Networking"],[Power BI]

Comment: @Johannes Yes, i need that particular output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this script what you need?

```
$arr = [  
   "IT" => [  
      "Programming" => [  
         0 => "Python",
         1 => "Java"
      ],
      "Networking" =>  [  
         0 => "CCNA"
      ]
   ],
   "Business" => [  
      "Power BI" => [  
         0 => "Power BI foundation"
      ]
   ]
];

$categories = [];
$subcategories = [];

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    array_push($categories, $key);
    array_push($subcategories, array_keys($value));
}
```

`$categories` equals:

```
["IT","Business"]
```

`$subcategories` equals :

```
[
  ["Programming","Networking"],
  ["Power BI"]
]
```

after execution.

Nevertheless, I would recommend to restructure your fetch script that has the array contained in `$arr` as output to avoid unnecessary loops.